# Npm permission denied on docker php:8.1.1-fpm-alpine3.15

Tags: php, docker, npm, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I get the following error message when I try to spin up my service via docker-compose:

> service_frontend  | npm ERR! code 128
>
> service_frontend  | npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
>
> service_frontend  | npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects clone -b feature/WHITELABEL-212-skeletons-während-der-lad https://bjoernme:***@bitbucket.org/faaren/faaren-ui.git /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneBmjHnf --recurse-submodules --depth=1
>
> service_frontend  | npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneBmjHnf': Permission denied
>
> service_frontend  |
>
> service_frontend  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> service_frontend  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-06-24T13_42_41_376Z-debug.log
>
> service_frontend exited with code 128

I have tried multiple constellations with in my docker-compose.yml for the user property, starting from root, root:root, node:node, 1000:1000, UID:GID (variables are set to inject my local user id and group id.

The relevant part from my docker-compose.yml:

```
  service_frontend:
    build:
      context: /workspace/faaren-services/frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        dev: "true"
    command: bash -c "npm install --save-dev chokidar@3.5.2 && composer install && php artisan octane:start --server=swoole --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --watch"
    user: root
    volumes:
      - /workspace/faaren-services/frontend:/var/www/html
      - ./docker-conf/supervisor/supervisord.conf:/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
      - ./docker-conf/php/debugger.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/debugger.ini
```

This is my local docker image:

```
FROM eu.gcr.io/faaren-prod/frontend-base-image:latest
COPY . /var/www/html
ARG dev=false
RUN if [ ${dev} = "true" ] ; then \
        set -ex \
        && apk add --no-cache npm \
        && mkdir -p /.npm \
        && mkdir -p /root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/ \
        && chmod 777 -R "/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/" \
        && chmod 777 -R "/.npm" \
    fi ;
```

And this is our internal base image (which is based on the [php:8.1.1-fpm-alpine3.15 image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/8.1.1-fpm-alpine3.15/images/sha256-33ad5ec8bc3efe8a2731285ab724890a728998b48c9e15acb047bf3d9a4ad4f2?context=explore):

```
FROM php:8.1.1-fpm-alpine3.15
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN apk add --no-cache --update git \
    npm 

RUN mkdir /.npm
RUN mkdir /.cache
RUN chown -R 1000:1001 "/.npm"
RUN chown -R 1000:1001 "/.cache"
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I've rduced the content of the shown file to a relevant minimum.

Comment: Do you really need two separate Dockerfiles? What about the docker-compose setup, can I copy'n'paste your file to reproduce the issue? What are the exact steps to reproduce the error you quote from the info you provide? Please carefully study the link I gave you, it should explain these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper into this issue I found out, that in Node 16.15.1 all commands within a npm task are run as the user who owns the current working dir. So even when running `npm i` as root subcommands as `git clone` are run as the user the current working dir belongs to.

In my case, `/var/www/html/` belongs to user:group 33333:33333. `npm i` was run as root. Coming to some `git clone` commands, those were run as user 33333. Therefor the user 33333 was not allowed to access the default cache npm folder under /root/.npm as this folder belongs to user root.

I fixed the problem the following way:

- create a cache dir outside of root `mkdir /var/www/.npm/cache`
- change ownership to 333333: `chown -R 33333:33333 /var/www/.npm/cache`
- set new directory as npm cache dir: `npm config set cache /var/www/.npm/cache --global`